# How to fetch a particular record?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like fetch the records of this year, which is not containing stop state here is my data. Is it possible to achieve by aggregate function?

this is my actual data

```
    { [
    {
      shortMovie":"name"
       "categrory": "comedy"
      "times": [
        {
          "state": "start",
          "date": "2017-1-09T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
{
          "state": "stop",
          "date": "2017-1-09T19:30:00.000Z"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "58b017bac8966e17dc59bd95"
    }
  ],[
    {
      shortMovie":"name"
       "categrory": "comedy"
      "times": [
        {
          "state": "start",
          "date": "2017-5-09T18:30:00.000Z"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "58b017bac8966e17dc59bd95"
    }
  ],
 [
    {
      shortMovie":"name"
       "categrory": "comedy"
      "times": [
        {
          "state": "start",
          "date": "2017-6-09T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
{
          "state": "pause",
          "date": "2017-6-09T19:30:00.000Z"
        },
{
          "state": "resume",
          "date": "2017-6-09T22:30:00.000Z"
        },
{
          "state": "stop",
          "date": "2017-6-09T23:30:00.000Z"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "58b017bac8966e17dc59bd95"
    }
  ]
}
```

i tried

```
const startDate = new Date(data.year, 0, 1),
                endDate = new Date(data.year, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999),
db.collection.find({$and: [{
                    $or: [{
                        "times.0.date": {
                            $gt: startDate,
                            $lt: endDate
                        }
                    }, {
                        "times.date": {
                            $gt: startDate,
                            $lt: endDate
                        }
                    }]
                }]}).toarray(function(result){

                                            result.times.map(function(get_time){
})
}
```

Comment: `.find({ "times.state": "stop" })` or even `.find({ "times.state": "stop" }, { "times.$": 1 })` to match the particular array element in the latter case. What's the problem?

Comment: sir i need to add two conditions one for current year and finding the entries which does not have `stop`. above i have returned the data which i got from map function

Comment: That is not what your question says. [Edit Your Question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44457555/edit) please. But really you "should" be reading the duplicate question link answers and learning something. There are more than enough cases presented there.

Comment: @NeilLunn yes i have updated please check

Comment: Like I said the preference is for you to actually [read the answers already given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection). There are examples there with `$filter`, which is the operator you need.